# `fprintf` with SD.h's File type

Tags: arduino, sd-card, printf

I'm using the `SD.h` library to write onto an SD card with the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). I need to write out in a file a template string with some placeholder replaced by certain values, in the way of `printf` behaves. I would use the `fprintf` function, but when I tried this:

```
File dataFile = SD.open("myfile.txt", FILE_WRITE);
fprintf(dataFile, "mynumber: %d\n", 100);
```

I got this error:

> cannot convert 'File*' to '__file*' for argument '1' to 'int
>   fprintf(__file*, const char*, ...)'

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**printf() makes your executable object ~1000 bytes larger, so you may not want to use it if size is a problem.**

The `fprintf` is not intended to use with the SD.h so I think

The simple solution that comes into my mind is using sprintf to format your text then write it to the file with the println function

```
File dataFile = SD.open("myfile.txt", FILE_WRITE);
char text[100];
sprintf(text,"My number: %d",yournumber);
dataFile.println(text);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now. I thought it was more clever to write straight to the file instead of passing through the ram, that's why I wanted to use fprintf. By the way, moving a bit off topic, what do you suggest to use instead of *printf/*scanf for writing and reading strings with placeholders?

Comment: The SD.h doesn't provide easy reading of data types there for you must implement your own or search for a library I didn't find one

Comment: I'll look forward to make a little parse/replace function by my own. As for the original question, i'm upvoting and marking as right your answer because it is indeed a solution. Mulțumesc!